# Xpath/Beautiful Soup... Is there a way to scrape based off of html output rather than the dom tree?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'd like to scrape the below html so that I can get `[u'Hero', u'Adventurer', u'King', u'Wizard', u'Marceline's Henchman', u'Nice Knight']`. I've tried a variety of different things with xpath, and I've also explored beautiful soup, but I feel there are too many extra rules that I'd like to squeeze into xpath to get the output that I want. Ex... I don't want anything in my output from the parenthesis, and I'd like things in the a tags outside of parentheses(like Marceline) to be one element together with other text that are in between the same br tags(like 's Henchman). I was wondering if there was some kind of alternative way of scraping that does not look at raw html, and instead looks at the actual web browser display of the html, because that's arranged really conveniently like a list. Is there anything out there that's along the lines of what I'm thinking?If there's nothing out there, I'm thinking about just parsing through this purely through python, but I'd first like to see what tools you've used to deal with moderately complicated scraping. Thanks!

This html snippet is a part of a larger document and I got this from writing this out:

```
occupation = data.xpath("tr[td/b[contains(.,'Occupation')]]/td[position()>1]").extract()[0]
print occupation

<td> Hero
    <br>Adventurer
    <br>King (formerly in "<a href="/wiki/The_Silent_King" title="The Silent King">The Silent King</a
    >")<br>Wizard (formerly in "<a href="/wiki/Wizard" title="Wizard" class="mw-redirect">Wizard</a>")
    <br><a href="/wiki/Mar
    celine" title="Marceline">Marceline</a>'s Henchman (formerly in "<a href="/wiki/Henchman" title="Henchman">Henchman</a>" )
    <br>Nice Knight (formerly in "<a href="/wiki/Loyalty_to_the_King" title="Loyalty to the King">Loyalty to the King</a>")
</td>
```

P.S. I suppose things in parentheses can be easily removed later through python, but it's coming up with a list where everything is separated by br tags that's a little confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways to manipulate xhtml data

1. xpath - the best way to parse and extract from the xhtml doc itself, scrapy `response.xpath('..')` you seem to know that already (well, there's also `.css('...')` selector, IMHO there is usually no reason to use it)
2. regular expression - the best way to match and manipulate free text, scrapy `response.xpath('..').re('<regex go here>')`
3. regular python - can be avoided in most cases

AFAIK no other magic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I came up with a regex solution half an hour ago. :D